# Connect the heater boiler through a relay instead of direct to the thermostat

Tags: hvac, relay

I am wiring up a new thermostat for an old boiler, and the thermostat I am using needs a common wire (Proliphix NT130h -- I wanted an `NT1X0e` series, which use PoE and don't need `C`, but they are no longer available).

The system uses a Honeywell "aquastat" controller that has an integrated transformer hooked up to `Rh` and `W`, so there's no way to add a common `C` to that transformer (short of what [this guy did](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/87424/how-can-i-connect-a-wifi-thermostat-to-a-honeywell-r845a-switching-relay#comment195604_87427) with taking apart the control unit and soldering a wire to the back of the board).

Here's what it looks like (though this is a much newer model, it looks pretty much the same):
[image: control unit]

Luckily, I have an additional 24VAC transformer right next to the boiler that I can use (it was meant to be used to power the thermostat for an air conditioning unit, but that unit was never installed, only the thermostat power and wires.
I know that I can theoretically use that transformer to power the thermostat by hooking it up to `Rc` and `C`. **However, the installation manual notes that `C` must be in phase with `Rh`,** which is not the case in my installation which has `C` in phase with `Rc`.

Since I don't think it will work to use only a single wire from the transformer (even though the manual says "in phase", I assume that it actually means "complete circuit"), I am trying to figure out another way to do this.

What I would like to do is hook up the heat through a relay.
That way, I can send power to the thermostat without needing separate `Rh` and `Rc` (in fact, since there is no AC, without needing `Rc` at all).

As I envision it, when the thermostat calls for heat, it will connect `Rh` to `W` which will connect the trigger side of the relay, which will close the circuit on the heater wires that used to go to `Rh` and `W`.

I have two concerns:

1. Is there any special relay I need, or will anything I find designed for low voltage work?
2. Do I need to worry that either side of the relay won't have enough of a load on it, possibly causing the equivalent of a short circuit on either of the transformers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I talked to a local HVAC repairman, and he said it should work, so I did it, and it works.

Here's what the circuit looks like:

[image: circuit diagram]